# plot count histogram in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I need help with this please.
I have searched here but not got the right output.

I am trying to plot this in R, so I can plot 3 files side-by-side in a single plot using GGplot.
The output I desire (plotted with excel) is this

[image: desired histogram]

What i am getting using GGplot is this

[image: ggplot output]

The R code i am using is this

```
A1 <- read.table("A1.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(A1, aes(x = count)) + geom_bar()
```

The data is a tab-delimited file like this

```
length  count
26  344776
27  289439
18  673395
28  338146
19  710702
20  928326
21  3491352
22  2724981
23  699007
24  726121
25  472509
```

The length, as it were will only be labels on the x axis for the counts plotted on the y-axis.

Comment: You don't need a histogram. You need a bar plot. Try a bar plot with length as x axis and count as y axis

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rohit. barplot works too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

`ggplot(A1, aes(x = as.character(length), y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works great. How can I make the labels on the x-axis correspond to each bar...like 18 19 20 21 etc. What i have now is 17.5 20.0 22.5 25.0 27.5

Comment: (stat="identity") appears to be the main difference to the code I wrote earlier. what is the meaning of this please?

Comment: if you dont use stat it would calculate the counts automatically. when you say stat="identity" you are basically saying 'dont count number of times you see 18 in lengths but take the count column as that value instead'

Comment: the labels are dependent on your length column. it should show exactly the same values. if you want integers you can use `round`

Comment: also you should mark this as answer if this was what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am quite aware that the labels are dependent on the length column. If you look at the desired plot that i posted in the OP, each label is printed below the corresponding bar. But in the plot i have now, it gives the labels at some interval and not for all the bar. For your suggestion of using round to get integers, where in the code do i put the round function